# Making query to find nearest multiple(Lat,Long) from the single(Lat,Long)

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

I am doing the nearest point query from a single point. Here is the sequence.
I have multiple POI stored in the MSSQLServer and the table is `dbo.Place`. The second table is `dbo.Position`, which will stored the collected GPS point.

I am using the Stored Procedure, and LatLong of Position is defined and available. How can I make query which is based from the examples below?

dbo.Place

```
Id   | Name   | Lat   | Long
1      POI1     1.735   4.73225
2      POI2     1.5665  3.9983
3      Tim2     1.4344  3.1282
```

The Lat Long variable is defined in the stored procedure. I would like to use the following formula to find the nearest point, which I will only take the nearest value from the 3 queries(assuming the sample data is 3 row)

```
SQRT(POW(X(`POI.Lat`) - 49.843317 , 2) + POW(Y(`POI.Long`) - 24.026642, 2)) * 100
```

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server already has spatial types and functions. Check [Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-2017). For simple points though, it's probably faster select only POIs within around the target with eg `where Lat between targetLat-tolerand and targetLon + tolerance` and only then calculate distances. You can use simple indexes on Lat and Lon fields to speed up the range search on the Lat, Lon fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL Server's geography functions for this.

```
DECLARE @InputLatitude FLOAT = 1.64
DECLARE @InputLongitude FLOAT = 4.25

DECLARE @GPS GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@InputLatitude, @InputLongitude, 4326)

SELECT TOP 1
    P.*,
    Distance = @GPS.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(P.Lat, P.Long, 4326))
FROM
    dbo.Place AS P
ORDER BY
    @GPS.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(P.Lat, P.Long, 4326)) ASC
```

You should consider adding a `GEOGRAPHY` column on your table with the GPS points already converted and adding a `SPATIAL INDEX` to speed up queries.

Comment: thank you @EzLo. This is what i need and it is working. But this is lack of the distance. How do I add the calculated distance between nearest POI and the inputLatLong ?

Comment: @encikpiee just add the distance calculation as a column expression. I've edited the answer.

Comment: great! thank you @EzLo . problem solved. thanks for the input. god bless you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the recommended geography types, you can also achieve the similar result using regular data types like float.

```
DECLARE @latitude FLOAT = 4.5678; -- Latitude of the place to search around
DECLARE @longitude FLOAT = 51.234; -- Longitude of the place to search around
DECLARE @range FLOAT = 100000; -- Max range in meters

SELECT TOP(1000)
    [place].[Lat],
    [place].[Long],
    ((((ACOS((SIN((PI() * [place].[Lat]) / 180.0) * SIN((PI() * @latitude) / 180.0)) + ((COS((PI() * [place].[Lat]) / 180.0) * COS((PI() * @latitude) / 180.0)) * COS((PI() * ([place].[Long] - @longitude)) / 180.0))) * 180.0) * 60.0) * 1.1515) * 1609.344) / PI() AS [Distance]
FROM [dbo].[Place] AS [place]
WHERE (((((ACOS((SIN((PI() * [place].[Lat]) / 180.0) * SIN((PI() * @latitude) / 180.0)) + ((COS((PI() * [place].[Lat]) / 180.0) * COS((PI() * @latitude) / 180.0)) * COS((PI() * ([place].[Long] - @longitude)) / 180.0))) * 180.0) * 60.0) * 1.1515) * 1609.344) / PI()) <= @range
ORDER BY [Distance]
```

Comment: Applying any functions *prevents* the server from using any indexes. Indexes would help with range searches though, eg converting the single point to a "box" that can be used to filter POIs before calculating the distance. `WHERE place.lat between @latitude - @delta and @latitude + @delta`

Comment: My mistake. Edited the answer.

Comment: SQL server execution plan does include index in the query. However, I'm not sure if that does have much significance in the performance.

Comment: Is it a seek or a scan though? The optimizer will *scan* the entire index if it can find what it wants there.