# How to find area around my current point lat and long

Tags: c#, sql-server, geolocation, geo

I have a point with latitude and longitude as (current place). In my Database, I have many points (lat & long) which show me stores (for example). I need a SQL Server query to get stores which are near my current place with 5 Kilometers distance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making query to find nearest multiple(Lat,Long) from the single(Lat,Long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626513/making-query-to-find-nearest-multiplelat-long-from-the-singlelat-long)

Comment: No. I checked that , my question is not duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [STDistance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) method:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE Location.STDistance(@CurrentPlace) <= 5000;
```

Comment: This answer would be so much better if it would also explain what type the variable `CurrentPlace` is and how to fill it

Comment: Thank you for the response. CurrentPlace save in two Columns , Lat(float) and Long(Float) ....

Comment: I Used STDistance method, and It is Ok. Thank you